# How to access service destination from approuter?

Tags: s4sdk, sap-cloud-sdk

It seems that I configured my approuter successfully:

[Approuter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKVtB.png)

I gave a destination to my service in SCP Cockpit:

[destination config in SCP Cockpit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUf0h.png)

And I maintained the destination in the xs-app.json:

```
    {
  "welcomeFile": "/webapp/index.html",
  "authenticationMethod": "route",
  "logout": {
    "logoutEndpoint": "/do/logout"
  },
  "routes": [
    {
      "source": "/destination",
      "target": "/",
      "destination": "service-destination"
    }
  ]
}
```

My question is now how can I access my service destination via approuter?

Shouldn't it be something like this:
https://qfrrz1oj5pilzrw8zations-approuter.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/webapp/index.html/destination

[Accessing service via Approuter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hB0TO.png)

...it returns Not found.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

This is my mta.yaml (if relevant):

```
    ID: oDataAuthorizations
_schema-version: '2.1'
version: 0.0.1
modules:
  - name: oDataAuthorizations-db
    type: hdb
    path: db
    parameters:
      memory: 256M
      disk-quota: 256M
    requires:
      - name: oDataAuthorizations-hdi-container
  - name: oDataAuthorizations-srv
    type: java
    path: srv
    parameters:
      memory: 1024M
    provides:
      - name: srv_api
        properties:
          url: '${default-url}'
    requires:
      - name: oDataAuthorizations-hdi-container
        properties:
          JBP_CONFIG_RESOURCE_CONFIGURATION: '[tomcat/webapps/ROOT/META-INF/context.xml: {"service_name_for_DefaultDB" : "~{hdi-container-name}"}]'
      - name: xsuaa-auto
  - name: approuter
    type: html5
    path: approuter
    parameters:
      disk-quota: 256M
      memory: 256M
    build-parameters:
      builder: grunt
    requires:
      - name: dest_oDataAuthorizations
      - name: srv_api
        group: destinations
        properties:
          name: service-destination
          url: '~{url}'
          forwardAuthToken: true
      - name: xsuaa-auto



resources:
  - name: oDataAuthorizations-hdi-container
    type: com.sap.xs.hdi-container
    properties:
      hdi-container-name: '${service-name}'
  - name: xsuaa-auto
    type: org.cloudfoundry.managed-service
    parameters:
      path: ./cds-security.json
      service-plan: application
      service: xsuaa
      config:
        xsappname: xsuaa-auto
        tenant-mode: dedicated
  - name: dest_oDataAuthorizations
    parameters:
      service-plan: lite
      service: destination
    type: org.cloudfoundry.managed-service
```

Comment: Just a guess, but `../index.html/destination` does not look correct to me. Have you tried it without the `index.html` file name?

Comment: When trying https://qfrrz1oj5pilzrw8zations-approuter.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/destination it looks somehow more promising since there seems to be a redirect. The URL changes to https://qfrrz1oj5pilzrw8zations-approuter.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/odata/v2/ but the result is still "Not found". This odata/v2 suffix seems to be coming already from my destination: https://gfuowb4ettq19agtuthorizations-srv.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/odata/v2/. But why is it not showing anything?

Comment: When I click the last link in your post, I get an HTML page now. That looks right to me.

Comment: The last link is my destination, which I want to reach via the approuter. So we are not there yet.

Comment: Oh, right, have not looked close enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two hosts:

- approuter
- srv

**The problem:**

- [https://approuter/destination/](https://qfrrz1oj5pilzrw8zations-approuter.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/destination/) will proxy to [https://srv/](https://gfuowb4ettq19agtuthorizations-srv.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/)

  Notice the root path in the URL. You see the path segment of your destination is ignored by the approuter. Instead it looks for the `routes[0].target` declaration of your `xs-app.json` file.

**The symptom:**

- [https://srv/](https://gfuowb4ettq19agtuthorizations-srv.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/) redirects (307) to `/odata/v2`. So does [https://approuter/destination/](https://qfrrz1oj5pilzrw8zations-approuter.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/destination/)
- [https://approuter/odata/v2/](https://qfrrz1oj5pilzrw8zations-approuter.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/odata/v2/) does not exist (404), no route was defined in your `xs-app.json`
- [https://approuter/destination/odata/v2/](https://qfrrz1oj5pilzrw8zations-approuter.cfapps.eu10.hana.ondemand.com/destination/odata/v2/) gives you the expected response.

**The solution:**

Adapt your `xs-app.json` to correctly refer the target endpoint path:

```
  "routes": [
    {
      "source": "/destination",
      "target": "/odata/v2",
      "destination": "service-destination"
    }
```

**Follow up**

Since your *srv* application statically references links to absolute path `/odata/v2`, you would either have to update each link in *srv* to use relative paths, **or** use `"/odata/v2/"` as your approuter route `source` to mirror the target. For the latter case you would miss out on the `"/destination"` path.